# PowerShell: Import-Module, but no "ExportedCommands" available

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, import-module

When I use

```
Import-Module -Name <path_to_local_dll> -Verbose
```

the cmdlets contained in the DLL file are not exported.

Thus, when I type `Get-Module` my imported module is listed, but without any ExportedCommands. Why?

```
ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Binary     MyModule
```

On a second PC with the same software (PowerShell, .NET Framework, ...), the same imported DLL file works fine. There I get ExportedCommands.

On what can this behaviour depend?

Unfortunately, the `Import-Module` cmdlet gives no indication that it failed to import the cmdlets. Is there a way to get an indication why it fails?

Comment: What version of .NET did you compile against and what version of System.Management.Automation.dll (1.0 or 3.0) does it reference? Also what version of PowerShell (and bitness) is the first machine running?  Is your assembly compiled Any CPU?

Comment: I didn't compiled the dll. I just use it. Thus, I don't know the version of .NET it was compiled against and the version of System.Management.Automation.dll.

I use 32 bit PowerShell 4.0. (PSVersion                      4.0,
WSManStackVersion              3.0,
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1,
    CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209,
    BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406,
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0},
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2)

Comment: Have you figured out the root cause of this problem? I'm having similar issue.
Please let me know if you have a solution/workaround. Thanks !

Comment: No, I didn't. As I had further problems based on this, I had to re-installed windows and all other stuff.

Comment: I was using a third-party tool (PS Protector) to convert *.psm1 to *.dll when I encountered this issue, despite having the *.psd1 file configured correctly. I actually was unable to locate the precise issue - it turned out that the problem was with the dll file, and generating the EXACT SAME dll with a slightly different name fixed the problem. Bizarre.

Answer (score 12):

Two things:

1. Make sure you're using a module manifest file (.psd1 file). More information can be found in *[How to Write a Module Manifest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878297(v=VS.85).aspx)*
2. Most importantly, edit your manifest file and make sure it references your root module as follows:

   RootModule = 'name of your module'

I just finished fighting with this for a few hours and I couldn't figure out what I was missing from my other modules. This did the trick for sure!

Comment: Is 'name of your module' with our without the ".psm1" extension? What does this power?

Comment: Without the .psm1. I just use the same module name. I created one called "CxdCallData" my manifest looks like: RootModule = "CxdCallData".

Answer (score 1):

One other requirement: ensure that the cmdlet class is *public*. For [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-attribute-declaration), in my .cs file I initially had:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Proc")]
class GetProcCommand : Cmdlet
{ ...
```

Even after adding a manifest file with `RootModule` set, `Get-Module` continued to show no `ExportedCommands` after my `Import-Module`. To fix it I just marked the class as public and rebuilt my .dll assembly:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Proc")]
public class GetProcCommand : Cmdlet
{ ...
```

I figured this out while examining my .dll using [ildasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/assemblies-gac/how-to-determine-if-a-file-is-an-assembly) - I noticed that some of my classes were public, but my cmdlet class was private.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the psd1 file (the module manifest) does not contain the commands.

[This page has a tutorial](http://mikefrobbins.com/2013/07/04/how-to-create-powershell-script-modules-and-module-manifests/) on how to create a module manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly exporting function from the PowerShell module worked for me:

```
function New-CmdLetNameHere
{
    ...
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function New-CmdLetNameHere
```