# Binary Powershell Cmdlet not exported from module

Tags: powershell, .net-assembly, powershell-cmdlet

I created a Powershell module containing one Cmdlet implemented by C# and some advanced functions provided by a psm1 file. When loading the module, only the functions implemented in advanced functions are exported.

I registered the assembly to load as part of my module and exported the functions:

```
RequiredAssemblies = @("lib\provider.dll","lib\myCmdlet.dll")
FunctionsToExport = @('New-assemblyFunction','New-advancedFunction')
```

Also I tried to mix the above functionstoexport with the cmdlettoexport for the assembly provided Cmdlet. All kind of combinations did not show any success:

```
CmdletsToExport = @('New-assemblyFunction')
```

If I start the import-module in verbose mode, I can see that the assemblies are being loaded but only functions implemented in advanced functions are being exported. The New-assemblyFunction does not appear anywhere in the verbose report.

I can load the DLL manually (import-module) and the cmdlet is available. 
Any clue what's wrong here or how to further analyse? I deblock-file'd all of them.

Comment: Value of `RequiredAssemblies` key not considered as PowerShell modules. You need to use `RootModule` (`ModuleToProcess`) or `NestedModules` key.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I added it as NestedModules and now the function has been exported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Import-Module, but no "ExportedCommands" available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082339/powershell-import-module-but-no-exportedcommands-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it:

Value of `RequiredAssemblies`key not considered as PowerShell modules. You need to use `RootModule` (`ModuleToProcess`) or `NestedModules` key. – *PetSerAl*